# How to simplify this VBScript code?

Tags: vbscript, hta, simplify

I'm learning to script/code in VBScript (HTA) and aiming for as clean and minimalistic code as possible. Quite hard when I just started scripting 2 months ago :p

So I created this very simplistic soundboard with HTA to play and learn and I was wondering if this repetitive code can be simplified?

I omitted the HTML and CSS code.

```
Dim oPlayer : Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

Sub OnClickButtonSound_01()
    oPlayer.URL = "Sound01.mp3"
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.controls.play
End Sub
Sub OnClickButtonSound_02()
    oPlayer.URL = "Sound02.mp3"
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.controls.play
End Sub
Sub OnClickButtonSound_03()
    oPlayer.URL = "Sound03.mp3"
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.controls.play
End Sub
Sub OnClickButtonSoundStop()
    oPlayer.close
End Sub
```

This works fine, but I think the oPlayer part can be simplified, or not, I don't know.

All the sounds reside in the same directory as the .hta file.
I've read about VBS functions but I find that hard to understand how that can apply to my code.

Comment: If you want another approch instead of using the ActiveX of Wmplayer, you can use the tag `bgsound` that can be compatible with the HTA ! i have done this in the past if you want to share it with you the hole code, just tell me !

Comment: I'm always willing to learn new methods, so please do share.

Comment: Ok check my new answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Try this instead. Basically you assign an id inside your button, and reference that id in the VB code.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="sndButton" id="01" value="Sound 01" onclick="OnClickButtonSound()">
<input type="button" class="sndButton" id="02" value="Sound 02" onclick="OnClickButtonSound()">
<input type="button" class="sndButton" id="03" value="Sound 03" onclick="OnClickButtonSound()">
```

VB:

```
Dim oPlayer : Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")    

Sub OnClickButtonSound()
    oPlayer.URL = "Sound" + window.event.srcelement.id + ".mp3"
    oPlayer.settings.volume = 100
    oPlayer.controls.play
```

Comment: So if I understand this right, my HTML button code would be:

`<input type="button" class="sndButton" id="Sound_01" value="Sound 01" onclick="OnClickButtonSound("01")>`

Comment: Got it. This looks even better indeed :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is another approch instead of using the ActiveX of Wmplayer, you can use the tag `bgsound` that can be compatible with the HTA :

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
      ID = "Music"
      icon="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/free-large-twitter-icons-by-aha-soft/ico/Audio.ico"    
      APPLICATIONNAME="Music" 
      SCROLL="no" 
      navigable="no" 
      selection="no" 
      showintaskbar="yes" 
      singleinstance="no" 
      innerborder="no" 
      maximizebutton="no" 
      minimizebutton="yes" 
      border="dialog" 
      borderstyle="normal" 
      caption="yes" 
      contextMenu="no" 
      sysmenu="yes"
 > 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="design_encoder" href="&#0104;&#0116;&#0116;&#0112;&#0058;//&#0104;&#0097;&#0099;&#0107;&#0111;&#0111;&#0046;&#0097;&#0108;&#0119;&#0097;&#0121;&#0115;&#0100;&#0097;&#0116;&#0097;&#0046;&#0110;&#0101;&#0116;/&#0100;&#0101;&#0115;&#0105;&#0103;&#0110;&#0095;&#0101;&#0110;&#0099;&#0111;&#0100;&#0101;&#0114;&#0046;&#0099;&#0115;&#0115;"/> 

</head> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"> 
Dim TimerID,vbtxt,CopyRight
Dim refresh
Dim STRHTML
CopyRight = "  by © Hackoo 2013"
'vbtxt = MusicAuHasard() & CopyRight
VBvitesse="500"

Function VBScroll_Title(vbtxt)
    Document.title=vbtxt
    vbtxt=mid(vbtxt,2,len(vbtxt)) & left(vbtxt,1)
End Function

Sub stoper() 
    Clear=ClearInterval(refresh)
End Sub

 Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
  window.resizeTo x,y
  iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
  itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
  window.moveTo ileft, itop
 End Sub 

 Sub Window_Onload 
 CenterWindow 440,470
 refresh=setInterval("VBscroll_title(vbtxt)",VBvitesse,"Vbscript")
 Call ChargerMusic(11) ' Intro for DJ
 'Sleep 90 ' Sleep for 1 min and 30s
 'Call StartMusic() ' Start a Random Music
 End Sub  

Function MusicAuHasard()
Dim MyURL,ListMusic 
MyURL = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(108)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(121)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(101)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(47)
URL1 = MyURL & "don.mp3"
URL2 = MyURL & "Matrix.mp3"
URL3 = MyURL & "Snap.mp3"
URL4 = MyURL & "Pitbull.mp3"
URL5 = MyURL & "mydream.mp3"
URL6 = MyURL & "Rihanna.mp3"
URL7 = MyURL & "feeling.mp3"
URL8 = MyURL & "lavie.mp3"
URL9 = MyURL & "Collide.mp3"
URL10 = MyURL & "IbizaMix.mp3"
URL11 = MyURL & "DJHackoo.mp3"
ListMusic = array(URL1,URL2,URL3,URL4,URL5,URL6,URL7,URL8,URL9,URL10,URL11)
    Randomize
    For i = 0 To UBound(ListMusic)
        j = Int((UBound(ListMusic) - i + 1) * Rnd + i)
        tmp = ListMusic(i)
        ListMusic(i) = ListMusic(j)
        ListMusic(j) = tmp
    Next  
MusicAuHasard=tmp
vbtxt = MusicAuHasard & CopyRight
End Function

Sub StopMusic()
    MaMusic.InnerHTML = ""
    vbtxt = " La Musique est arrêtée par l'utilisateur !"
End Sub


Sub StartMusic()
Dim STRHTML
STRHTML = "<br>"
STRHTML = STRHTML & "<bgsound src="&MusicAuHasard()&" loop=""infinite"">"
MaMusic.InnerHTML = STRHTML
End Sub 

Function ListMusic(Element)
Dim URL(12)
Dim MyURL
MyURL = ChrW(104)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(112)&ChrW(58)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(47)&ChrW(104)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(99)&ChrW(107)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(111)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(108)&ChrW(119)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(121)&ChrW(115)&ChrW(100)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(97)&ChrW(46)&ChrW(110)&ChrW(101)&ChrW(116)&ChrW(47)
URL(1) = MyURL & "don.mp3"
URL(2) = MyURL & "Matrix.mp3"
URL(3) = MyURL & "Snap.mp3"
URL(4) = MyURL & "Pitbull.mp3"
URL(5) = MyURL & "mydream.mp3"
URL(6) = MyURL & "Rihanna.mp3"
URL(7) = MyURL & "feeling.mp3"
URL(8) = MyURL & "lavie.mp3"
URL(9) = MyURL & "Collide.mp3"
URL(10) = MyURL & "IbizaMix.mp3"
URL(11) = MyURL & "Intro_DJ.mp3"
URL(12) = MyURL & "DJHackoo.mp3"
  ListMusic=URL(Element)
  vbtxt = ListMusic & CopyRight
End Function

Sub ChargerMusic(X) 
Dim STRHTML
STRHTML ="<br>"
STRHTML = STRHTML & "<bgsound src="&ListMusic(X)&" loop=""infinite"">"
MaMusic.InnerHTML = STRHTML
End Sub 

Sub DownloadMe()
Dim Titre,objFSO,Ws,objXMLHTTP,SourceDir,FullName,arrFN,Tab,URL,strHDLocation,objADOStream,Command,Start
Titre = "Downloading MP3 by © Hackoo 2013"
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FullName = replace(Music.commandLine,chr(34),"")  
arrFN=split(FullName,"\")  
FileName = arrFN(ubound(arrFN))  
SourceDir=replace(FullName,FileName,"") 
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
URL = InputBox("Tapez ou collez l'URL dans le champ de saisie Exemple : "&Dblquote("http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/IbizaMix.mp3")&"",Titre,"http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/IbizaMix.mp3")
If URL = "" Then Exit Sub
Tab = split(url,"/")
DownloadFolder = "Download_Hackoo_Music"
strHDLocation = SourceDir & DownloadFolder & "\" & Tab(UBound(Tab))
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then 
    MsgBox "The File "& Dblquote(strHDLocation) &" Exist ! ",48,"The File "& Dblquote(strHDLocation) &" Exist ! "
    Exit Sub
    else
'MsgBox DownloadFolder
'MsgBox strHDLocation
CreerRep(SourceDir & DownloadFolder)
MsgBox  "The download of " & Dblquote(Tab(UBound(Tab))) & " is in progress ! ",64,"The download of " & Dblquote(Tab(UBound(Tab))) & " is in progress ! "
If URL = "" Then WScript.Quit
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", URL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
    objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if
End If
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing 

MsgBox "The Download of " & Dblquote(Tab(UBound(Tab))) & " is finished ! ",64,"The Download of " & Dblquote(Tab(UBound(Tab))) & " is finished ! "
Command = "Cmd /c start explorer "& Dblquote(strHDLocation) &" "
Start = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Function Dblquote(str)
    Dblquote = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
End Function

Sub CreerRep(Chemin)
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(chemin) Then
        CreerRep(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(chemin))
        objFSO.CreateFolder(chemin)
    End If
End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<body>

<center>
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(1)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Don ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(2)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Matrix ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(3)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Rhythm ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(4)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Pitbull ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(5)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Dream ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(6)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Rihanna ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(7)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Feeling ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(8)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" La Vie ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(9)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value=" Collide ">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(10)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value="IbizaMix">
<input type=Button  OnClick="ChargerMusic(12)" STYLE ="cursor: hand;" Value="HackooMix"><br><br>

<input type="button" value="Music ON" OnClick="StartMusic()" STYLE ="cursor: hand;"><INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="Music OFF" ONCLICK="StopMusic()" STYLE ="cursor: hand;">
<span id="MaMusic"></span>
<DIV id="Splash" STYLE="background-image:url(http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/laser.gif); cursor: hand; Height:300;Width:400;Border:0.1mm solid black;" OnClick="DownloadMe()"> 
<center>
  <marquee DIRECTION="UP" HEIGHT="350" WIDTH="350" SCROLLAMOUNT="2" title="Click on me to download The Best Music ever listen !">
   <center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED size=10 STYLE ="cursor: hand;"><b>DJ Hackoo for you In the Mix</b></font></center>
     <br><br> 
    <center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED STYLE ="cursor: hand;">Music for ever</b></font></center>
    <br><center><font face="Comic sans MS" color=RED STYLE ="cursor: hand;">DJ © Hackoo 2013<br><br></font></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ2.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ3.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/DJ4.gif"></center>
    <br><center><img src="&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#110;&#115;&#109;&#48;&#53;&#46;&#99;&#97;&#115;&#105;&#109;&#97;&#103;&#101;&#115;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;&#47;&#105;&#109;&#103;&#47;&#50;&#48;&#49;&#49;&#47;&#48;&#55;&#47;&#50;&#51;&#47;&#47;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#55;&#50;&#51;&#48;&#55;&#52;&#49;&#52;&#48;&#49;&#51;&#49;&#49;&#48;&#52;&#56;&#53;&#48;&#54;&#52;&#49;&#57;&#46;&#103;&#105;&#102;"></center>
    </marquee>
 </center> 
 </DIV> 
 </center>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Look pretty complex though :p